# I want to print the status of connection. like my phone is connected in wifi or gprs. in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wifi

I don't want to show the available connection. I just want to show that am i connected with gprs or wifi. that's it.

Comment: what does it mean to show in android studio?

Comment: that's good that you want it. What is a problem? what is a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ConnectivityManager class.. OR Follow this link You will get What you want.

[Connectivity Manager](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html)

Comment: cool bro. its helped :D

Comment: Make it as a correct answer